# Google App Engine, Does empty properties in datastore entities cost money

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Google App Engine, Does empty properties in datastore entities cost money??

In 'Datastore Statistics' tab of my app's admin page

i get '**NULL   56 Bytes** '

i guessed from the following docs that the empty properties will not use memory

"a given row in a Bigtable table may have different columns than any other row before it. In this sense, a Bigtable functions as a large, sorted, multi-dimensional array with each row having a collection of columns, which may or may not be the same set of columns of other rows in the same table."

http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/storage_breakdown.html

Comment: not all properties of the entity are empty –

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Empty properties have to be stored as well, because the key exists, even if the value does not. There is a difference between an empty property and a non-existing property.

Comment: Thanks @Thilo
but not all properties of the entity are empty

Comment: He didn't say they were. Consider two dictionaries: {'name': 'thing1', 'other_property': None} and {'name': 'thing2'}. On the first, other_property is null; on the second it is missing. Even when the value is null, the key still takes up space in the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks every one,
Now I am using polymodel to save money